# When is asyncio.Lock() needed?

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio, coroutine

Here is the code I have so far that uses the bleak package to connect to multiple Bluetooth devices and get data/notifications from them. The devices are scales are they automatically shut off after awhile if there are no weights on them. Upon placing weight on them, they turn on and starts notifying. The code continuously scan for devices that are on, to log data from them. Upon shutting off, the disconnect_callback() function will be called.

I have a global set called connected_devices that keeps track of the devices that are on. When a device is connected, its MAC address will be added to the set. When a device disconnect, its Mac address will be removed from the set (in the disconnect_callback() function).

I have locking codes that are currently commented out in order to synchronize the adding/removal of MAC addresses from the connected_device set, but I'm not sure is necessary, since everything runs in the scan_and_connect() coroutine.

```
import asyncio
import functools
from bleak import BleakClient, BleakScanner

#lock = asyncio.Lock()  
connected_devices = set() 
notify_uuid = "00002A37-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"

def callback(client, characteristic, data):
    print(client.address, characteristic, data)

def disconnected_callback(client):
    #with lock: 
    connected_devices.remove(client.address)
    print("disconnect from", device.address)

def match_device(device, adv_data):
    #with lock:
    return adv_data.local_name.startswith('BLE') and device.address not in connected_devices

async def scan_and_connect():
    while True:
        device = await BleakScanner.find_device_by_filter(match_device)

        if device is None:
            continue

        client = BleakClient(device, disconnected_callback=disconnected_callback)
        try:
            await client.connect()
            print("connected to", device.address)
            await client.start_notify(functools.partial(callback, client))
            #with lock:
            connected_devices.add(device.address)

        except BleakError:
            # if failed to connect, this is a no-op, if failed to start notifications, it will disconnect
            await client.disconnect()
     

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(scan_and_connect())
```

Can someone advise whether the locks are necessary in this case?
Thanks

Comment: There's no opportunity for the state to be inconsistent here.  At any given point, a device might be in or out, but there's no place where a device is half-in or half-out.  Thus, the locks aren't needed.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs [BleakClient class](https://bleak.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/client.html)

> disconnected_callback – Callback that will be scheduled in the event
> loop when the client is disconnected.

asyncio guarantees that no other coroutine using the same event loop will run between awaited calls. So you don't have to worry that your set operation will be interrupted and there is no reason for a lock.

If this set is altered outside of the event loop, that's a different story. But the lock still wouldn't be useful unless everything that uses the set uses the same lock.

The risky thing about this code is that it assumes there is always a one-to-one relationship between bleak callbacks and the addresses being tracked. You really should wrap `connected_devices.remove(client.address)` in an exception handler just in case.

`asyncio.Lock` is needed when you need to maintain a stable state across an `await` call where another coroutine could execute and change that state.

Comment: plus also: no need in Python to protect adding data to sets, dictionaries or lists at all, even in multi-threaded code; these operations are atomic.

Comment: @jsbueno - True, but there is a window between loading `client.address` and calling `remove` where code in another thread can run. Depending on the situation, it may require a lock.

Comment: the risky thing you mentioned can happen when the connect() or start_notify() in the try statement fails so the address was never added to the set, so then disconnect() will try to remove an address from the set that doesn't exist right? I can't think of other situations where there wouldn't be an one-to-one relationship between bleak callbacks and the address being tracked. thanks

Comment: @dataengineer22 - That seems reasonable. But add before doing `await client.start_notify` because the notification could happen before that call returns.